# How can I add a payment method in a flutter app? there are some packages but they aren't well explained

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

And please can someone give me some advices when using payments

Comment: Which payment gateway you want to add?

Answer (score 2):

I use [RevenueCat](https://pub.dev/packages/purchases_flutter), it is super easy to set up, and they have very good documentation on their [site](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/flutter).

Its free to start to use, but after you start making more than 10k a month, they will start to charge you.

I really like this plugin because you have more control over your purchases, both iOS and Android, You can change them while in production, grant users free access, and a lot more. They have reporting, and it seems to work alright. It could be improved though.

Answer (score 2):

All this depends on whether you are selling digital goods through the app, or just selling premium content.

If you are selling premium content, you will have to use in app purchases, and set them on the individual app stores.

Please take a look at this in app purchases plugin, to get started.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase

Please note that according to apple if you are selling premium content (non digital goods) on iOS, and if you are not using in app purchases your app will be rejected.

> 3.1.1 In-App Purchase: If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game
> currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a
> full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not use their
> own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license
> keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. Apps and their
> metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to
> action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than
> in-app purchase.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments

If you are selling digital goods, products through the app, then you will need to use a payment gateway. There are plenty of options: Stripe, RevenueCat, BrainTree, American Express, etc.